# Read a file then store numbers in array C

Tags: c, arrays, file

so I have this file called "score.txt" with contents

```
NAME
20
NAME2
2
```

And I'm using this code but it gets an error and I have no idea on how to put the integers from the file in an array.

```
int main(){

FILE* file = fopen ("score.txt", "r");
 int i = 0;

  fscanf (file, "%d", &i);    
  while (!feof (file))
{  
  printf ("%d ", i);
  fscanf (file, "%d", &i);      
}
  fclose (file);
 system("pause");
 }
```

I'm only self learning and i've been trying to figure this out for 2hours already

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `fscanf` for input where some lines will fail the format is that the file will not be advanced per iteration of the `while` loop, so you get stuck.

You can get a solution by using `fgets` to grab the data and `sscanf` to grab the number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    char buf[50];

    FILE *file = fopen("score.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
         fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),file)) {
         ret = sscanf(buf,"%d",&i);
         if (ret == 1) { // we expect only one match
               printf("%d\n", i);
         } else if (errno != 0) {
               perror("sscanf:");
               break;
         }
     }
     fclose(file)
     return(0);
}
```

This will output, for your input:

```
20
2
```

We check the output of `sscanf` as it tells us if the format has been matched correctly, which will only happen on the lines with integer, and not the 'NAME' lines. We also check for 'errno' which will be set to non-zero if `sscanf` encounters an error.

We used `char buf[50];` to declare a char array with 50 slots, which `fgets` then uses to store the line its reading; however if the line is more than 50 chars in length it will be read in 50 char chunks by `fgets`, and you may not get the results you desire.

If you wish to store the integers you read into an array, you'll have to declare an array, then on each read assign a slot in that array to the value of the int you read i.e. `int_array[j] = i` (where `j` will have to change with each slot you use). I'll leave it as an exercise to implement this.